# Python Selenium Program Not Running - Terminates Immediately

Tags: python, selenium

I am currently playing around with selenium - I had used it briefly in the past with no issues. But, now, when I try to run a script, the program just ends immediately. This is the terminal output:

```
Christophers-MacBook-Pro-3:~ christophergreene$ cd Desktop
Christophers-MacBook-Pro-3:Desktop christophergreene$ python awol.py
Christophers-MacBook-Pro-3:Desktop christophergreene$
```

Any idea why? Am i missing something that selenium needs to run?

All help appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Which driver are you using?

Comment: Using Chromedriver

Comment: What is the version of chromedriver and chrome browser that you are using?

Comment: @JustinJoy earlier i redownloaded Chromedriver so it is on the latest version

Comment: and the chrome browser you are using?

Comment: @JustinJoy yes - up to date